# Using "The" article at the beginning of (table) titles and figure captions including "of" phrase

Tags: definite-articles, titles

What's good practice for writing titles for academic papers and their tables, and captions for figures.

The baseline characteristics of the included patients.

**OR**

Baseline characteristics of the included patients.

Comment: Both are fine. I'd expect to see the second more often, and also sometimes a third with no "the" before "included patients." Considering that articles are omitted to save space and provide a brief summary, decide based on clarity and how much space you have under the figure.

Comment: Paradoxically, omitting articles in headings / labels can appear the more professional option.

Comment: Labels need to be as short as possible when displaying information; that usually means leaving articles and other grammar words out. Titles need to be as informative as possible; that usually means leaving at least some of them in. Plus titles come before any information their contents contain and can't presuppose it, whereas captions for figures can. "Included patients" wouldn't do in a paper title, for instance, though it'd be fine in a caption.

Comment: The short form is fine, the conventions relating to data captions are similar to those relating to newspaper headlines.